# Snowflake COPY INTO fails on double quote value in a data value

Tags: load, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

COPY INTO is failing due to a double quote being found within the data value.
The two double quotes around C causes the failure -> NE 845 "C" Street.

The exact error message is:

> Found character 'H' instead of field delimiter '|~' File '@~/FolderX/datafile.dat.gz', line 1, character 107 Row 274598, column
>   "MY_TABLE"["BADCOLUMN":20] If you would like to continue loading when
>   an error is encountered, use other values such as 'SKIP_FILE' or
>   'CONTINUE' for the ON_ERROR option. For more information on loading
>   options, please run 'info loading_data' in a SQL client.

The Format File is defined as:

```
CREATE FILE FORMAT "DW"."STG".FMT_FILE 
COMPRESSION = 'GZIP' 
FIELD_DELIMITER = '|~' 
RECORD_DELIMITER = '\n' 
SKIP_HEADER = 0 
FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\042' 
TRIM_SPACE = TRUE 
ERROR_ON_COLUMN_COUNT_MISMATCH = FALSE 
ESCAPE = '#' 
ESCAPE_UNENCLOSED_FIELD = 'NONE' 
DATE_FORMAT = 'AUTO' 
TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'AUTO' 
ENCODING = 'WINDOWS1253'
NULL_IF = ('\\N');
```

Why does it care if double quote exists within any value when the data is:

```
123|~NE 845 "C" Street|~PULLMAN
```

There should be no need, given the definition of the format file, add an escape within any string.  This failure seems like a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a bug.  You've explicitly asked Snowflake to recognize a double-quote as a way of enclosing values within your file when you used this statement `FIELD_OPTIONALLY_ENCLOSED_BY = '\042'`.  If you remove that (or change to `NONE`) from your file format, you shouldn't receive the error that you are receiving.  Snowflake is behaving as expected, though.

Comment: Snowflake is using ASCII octal 42, the MSFT world uses ASCII decimal.  Looking at the ASCII table made me expected for the code to complain about asterisk rather than double quote.   Thanks!